# Command to measure TLB misses on LINUX

Tags: linux, profiling, tlb

Could some one direct me to a command to measure TLB misses on LINUX, please? Is it okay to consider minor page faults as TLB misses?

Comment: I have no idea; TLB misses are deep inside the processor. page fauts are not TLB misses.

Comment: Minor page faults not major page faults?

Comment: What CPU family ? I'm guessing x86-64 but you need to specify the processor for this as any solution may involve accessing CPU performance registers ?

Comment: @Paul R: You mean that I need to monitor performance counters.

Comment: @kkp: possibly - some CPUs have a performance register for TLB misses, some don't - see the discussion under this article: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `perf` to do this. Provided your CPU supports it.

Use `perf list` to get some idea of the counters available. When I took this list and grepped for TLB (on my Sandy Bridge machine) I got:

```
rob@tartarus:~$ perf list | grep -i tlb
  dTLB-loads                                         [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-load-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-stores                                        [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-store-misses                                  [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-prefetches                                    [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-prefetch-misses                               [Hardware cache event]
  iTLB-loads                                         [Hardware cache event]
  iTLB-load-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
```

You can then use this particular counter with: `perf record -e <event0>,<event1>,..`

And then just use `perf report` to look at the results.

Comment: `oprofile` may also have access to TLB miss counters, for older kernels.

Comment: I've used `oprofile` in the past too - unfortunately the version shipping in Fedora 16 is one release behind the one that includes support for Sandy Bridge. I didn't want to recommend something I couldn't test.

Answer (score 7):

To see this information for the entire system, you could use the following line. This will record the counters for 1 minute (60 seconds).

```
perf stat -e dTLB-loads,dTLB-load-misses,iTLB-loads,iTLB-load-misses sleep 60
```

If miss ratio is higher than 1% you should look into using *huge pages*.